# How to solve this kind of problems?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

For $[z^n]\frac{z^k}{1-z^k}$ we can get $[z^n]\frac{z^k}{1-z^k}=\left(               
  \begin{array}{ccc}   
    n-1\\  
    k-1\\ 
  \end{array}
\right)$

But $[z^n](z\frac{1-z^r}{1-z})^k=?$

How to solve this kind of problems in general? What are the techniques?

Comment: What is $z$ in your equation?

Comment: As you may have noticed, I've been adding the [tag:generating-functions] tag to your questions about generating functions. Please start adding it yourself in case you ask further questions about generating functions.

Comment: @Inceptio: The notation $[z^n]$ denotes extracting the coefficient of $z^n$ in the power series for the expression that follows. Thus $z$ is just a dummy variable here.

Comment: $[z^n]\frac{z^k}{1-z^k}$ is coefficient of $z^n$ in $f(z)$

Comment: No, that would be a rather bizarre notation. It's the coefficient of $z^n$ in $\dfrac{z^k}{1-z^k}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the trivial splitting of the generating function:
$$
   g(z) = \left( z \frac{1-z^r}{1-z} \right)^k = \underbrace{\frac{z^k}{(1-z)^k} }_{g_1(z)} \cdot \underbrace{\left(1-z^r \right)^k}_{g_2(z)}
$$
along with established facts $[z^n] (1-z)^{-\alpha} = \binom{\alpha+n-1}{n}$:
$$
   [z^n] \frac{z^k}{(1-z)^k} = [z^{n-k}] \left(1-z\right)^{-k} = \binom{k + (n-k) -1}{n-k}
 = \binom{n-1}{n-k} = \binom{n-1}{k-1}
$$
and
$$
   [z^n] \left(1-z^r \right)^k = [z^n] \sum_{m=0}^k \binom{k}{m} (-1)^m z^{m r} = (-1)^{n/r}\binom{k}{n/r} [ n \bmod r = 0]
$$
The series coefficients for the product of $g_1$ and $g_2$ is the Cauchy sum of series coefficients of individual generating functions:
$$
   [z^n] g(z) = \sum_{m=0}^n [z^{n-m}] g_1(z) \cdot [z^m] g_2(z) = \sum_{m=0}^{\left\lfloor n/r \right\rfloor} (-1)^m  \binom{n-1 - m  r}{k-1} \binom{k}{m}
$$